# Excel Tables auto populate

Tags: excel

I have a rather large table that is auto updated from an online form. There are sometimes hundreds of entries that are added a day by employees. In the same workbook I would like to make separate pages for each supervisor to approve the entries. I have the exact same table layout on each page for each supervisor. When an entry is added to the main table I would like to pull all entries that equal “John Doe” and add a copy to his page and his table so that he can view only the entries that apply to them and approve or make changes as needed and then have those changes update and be reflected on both his sheet and the main sheet/table. Same with the other 10 supervisors is this possible? I have all pages names with supervisors name and have made tables with a unique name as well.

I’ve tried table connections and don’t get the result I was expecting. Not sure where else to try

Comment: You may want to be more specific in your question and title. Here's an article that might have some good info for you. Specifically 'paste link'. https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/data-entry/automatically-update-data-in-another-sheet

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the Kutools extension for this.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4706-google-sheets-copy-row-to-another-sheet.html

Once you have that installed, go to select > select specific cells. Enter in the values you need to select by. You'll likely need to select the whole column. Once that's done, go to your destination, select the upper left corner of where you want the info to go, right click and select `paste link`. This should link your special selection to the new page.